# What is correct type of object and string's array?

Tags: typescript

Here is an array example.

```
const arr = [
  {name: ['foo1', 'foo2']},
  'bar',
  'baz'
];
```

and, here is an error type example.
The error is "Type 'string' is not assignable to type".

```
type Arr = {
  { [key: string]: string[] }[]
}
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (this is a link to a web IDE with your code in it)](https://tsplay.dev/NBP1VW), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing with no typos. This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type Arr = Array<string | {[key: string]: string[]}>

const a: Arr = ['1','2',{'1': ['1','2']}];
```